# Linear technology power supply, question about a transistors

Tags: power-supply, transistors, resistor-transistor-logic

On page 12 of [this journal](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/lt-journal-article/ltjournal-v24n2-2014-07.pdf) there is a power supply design by LT. On page 14 there is a complete schematic.

[image]

I understand everything but these two parts:

There is a negative supply of -5V connected at the output and it draws, through a resistor, 8mA so LT3081 can function normally and output near 0V. Voltage drop on the resistor is 4.4V.

**Q1:  What purpose does this transistor have? Could one use a slightlly bigger resistor to achieve 5V drop on it and do the same thing?**
[image]

**Q2: Why is this transistor here? Would it be the same without it?**
[image]

Comment: \$Q_5\$ has its base nailed to ground. So it's a constant current (ignoring temp changes) source/sink (perspective is all) at the collector. \$Q_4\$ is a very fast way (avoiding Miller effect) of passing along a signal but isolating it to protect the input. If you pull up on the emitter the collector is actively pulled towards the input voltage. Otherwise, the 10k pull-down operates if the input at the emitter is ground (or near so.) It's actually a good addition here, I think. I should probably use it more often.

Answer (score 1):

```
Q5 takes a regulated 8 mA constant current from the output of the LT3081
```

The base of Q5 is at 0 volts and this means the emitter is 0.7 volts lower at -0.7 volts. This means that the voltage across the 549 ohm resistor is about 4.3 volts. 4.3 volts / 549 ohms = 7.83 mA.

In other words the ~8 mA is a constant "drag" from the LT3081 and allows it to operate down to 0 volts. You could use a simple resistor to pull 8 mA from that point but consider what happens when the LT3081 is outputting (say) 24 volts. A simple resistor that takes 8 mA from (ostensibly) 0 volts to - 5 volts would have a value of 625 ohms BUT that would take a current of (24 + 5) volts / 625 ohms (=46.4 mA) when the LT3081 output is at 24 volts and this is deemed to be either too inefficient or just plain "too much".

It's less clear to me what Q4 does other than to put INT_Vcc onto the RUN pin of the LTC3632. Maybe someone else can spot the reason.

Comment: See my comment to the OP.